# Дочерним действиям не разрешается выполнять действия перенаправления. Как решить проблему с перенаправлением дочерних действий?

Tags: c#, mvc

Столкнулся со следующим исключением.

> Дочерним действиям не разрешается выполнять действия перенаправления.

Есть _Layout и в нем `@Html.Action("Create", "Elys")` - страница представления с полями для ввода имени и номера телефона.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Number)
    <div class="">
        <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
}
```

Есть контроллер который при успешной операции должен перенаправить на другую страницу.. но в итоге исключение с сообщением о невозможности выполнить действие перенаправления.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Call call)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveCall(call);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format("Ваш номер телефона \"{0}\" сохранен.", call.Number);
        return RedirectToAction("ElysDream");
    }
```

При этом в базу введенные данные сохраняются.
Как решить данную проблему?

Comment: "исключение с сообщением о невозможности выполнить действие перенаправления" - не надо вольных пересказов сообщений об ошибках. Приведите точное сообщение, добавив его в вопрос.

Comment: Он написан был в самом начале. В вопрос добавил.